# Gson is unable to serialize LocalDateTime data in Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, gson

*[UPDATED:02.20.2023] I was misused between LocalDateTime and Instant data type in my example so I adjusted it. Sorry for this inconvenient. Thank you*

I am practicing coding and facing an issue relating to Gson and LocalDateTime in Java Android.
For example, I created a Java object

```
public class Person {
private String name;
private LocalDateTime createdAt;

// Constructors
// Getters and Setters
}
```

Then I used Gson to convert this Person object in to Json

```
Person person = new Person("John Doe", LocalDateTime.now()); //For example: 2022-02-02T11:11:045701100
String personJsonAsString = new Gson().toJson(person);
```

I expect the Json should be

```
{
"name": "John Doe",
"createdAt": "2022-02-02T11:11:045701100"
}
```

But the result I got was

```
{
"name": "John Doe",
"createdAt": {} // <- It's empty here
}
```

After that, I researched and found that I can add custom serializer class into GsonBuilder instance so I tried again

```
Person person = new Person("John Doe", LocalDateTime.now()); //For example: 2022-02-02T11:11:510Z
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = builder.registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeJsonSerializer()).create();
String personJsonAsString = gson.toJson(person);
```

While `LocalDateTimeJsonSerializer` is a class that I wrote

```
public class LocalDateTimeJsonSerializer implements JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(LocalDateTime src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(src.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
    }
}
```

The exception was throw when I try to persist the data on the Android app like this:
[image]

For now, I cannot figure out what makes LocalDateTime cannot be serialized in Android Platform by Gson. Please help me. Thank you so much for your time.

What I did try:
Researching other questions on Stackoverflow.
Try out any available solutions.
What I was expecting:
I was expecting to know the actual root cause of the exception instead of fixing the bug and making it run only

Comment: I recommend posting the stack trace as text, not an image. If you put a breakpoint inside your `serialize()` method, does `src` look correct? It feels like there is some issue with the `LocalDateTime` itself. Also, which `LocalDateTime` are you using? There are a few options for that, including Java 8 desugaring and ThreeTenABP.

Comment: If you just run `LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)`, does the same exception occur then as well? In that case this is probably unrelated to Gson.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, I debugged and all data seems to be correct. I use the LocalDateTime which is from java.time package. I'll read about the desugaring and ThreeTenABP. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi, Marcono1234, yes. the exception is thrown. I need to tried again. I believe it is not because of Gson but the compatibility of dependencies and Android platform... Still, I need to research more. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @TrânVõBảo, I would also recommend using [`GsonBuilder.addReflectionAccessFilter(ReflectionAccessFilter.BLOCK_ALL_PLATFORM)`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#addReflectionAccessFilter(com.google.gson.ReflectionAccessFilter)) to avoid using Gson's reflection-based adapter for Android library classes by accident. Otherwise you rely on their implementation details, which could differ between Android versions.

Answer (score 3):

## Square peg in a round hole

Wrong class. Use `Instant`, not `LocalDateTime`.

```java
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Instant createdAt;
    …
}
```

Your input `"2022-02-02T11:11:510Z"` has a `Z` on the end. That letter indicates an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2022-02-02T11:11:510Z" ) ;
```

The `LocalDateTime` lacks any concept of offset or time zone. So that class cannot represent a moment, is not a specific point on the timeline. That class cannot represent the meaning intended by your input. That class cannot be used to record the moment something was created.

Your input string complies with ISO 8601 standard. See Wikipedia.

You showed line of code:

> `Person person = new Person("John Doe", LocalDateTime.now());`

I cannot imagine a case where calling `LocalDateTime.now` is the right thing to do.

Change to:

```
Person person = new Person( "John Doe" , Instant.now() ) ;
```

### Example code

I am no expert on [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson). But I seem to have gotten the following to work.

For brevity, let's define your `Person` class as a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395). I am pleased to see that the current version 2.10.1 of Gson seems to be working well with records.

```java
package work.basil.example.gson;

import java.time.Instant;

public record Person( String name , Instant createdAt ) { }
```

Apparently the only date-time type adapter bundled with GSON is for `java.util.Date`. That terrible legacy class should be avoided. Use only *java.time* classes.

We are using `java.time.Instant`. So we need to write our own type adapter. You can find 3rd party open-source type adapter implementations. But writing your own for `Instant` is simple enough.

The *java.time* classes by default use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats when parsing/generating text. So we will use that standard.

```java
package work.basil.example.gson;

import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Instant;

public class Gson_InstantTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter < Instant >
{
    @Override
    public void write ( JsonWriter jsonWriter , Instant instant ) throws IOException
    {
        jsonWriter.value( instant.toString() );  // Writes in standard ISO 8601 format.
    }

    @Override
    public Instant read ( JsonReader jsonReader ) throws IOException
    {
        return Instant.parse( jsonReader.nextString() );   // Parses standard ISO 8601 format.
    }
}
```

Now we write an app to exercise these classes.

First, define a `Gson` object to be using for generating and parsing JSON text.

```java
Gson gson =
        new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter( Instant.class , new Gson_InstantTypeAdapter() )
                .create();
```

Write some JSON.

```java
// Write to JSON.
Person person = new Person( "John Doe" , Instant.now() ); //For example: 2022-02-02T11:11:510Z
String personAsJson = gson.toJson( person );
```

> personAsJson = {"name":"John Doe","createdAt":"2023-02-19T22:47:42.566132Z"}

And read some JSON.

```java
// Parse JSON.
Person p = gson.fromJson( personAsJson , Person.class );
```

> p.toString() = Person[name=John Doe, createdAt=2023-02-19T22:47:42.566132Z]

Bring that code together.

```java
package work.basil.example.gson;

import com.google.gson.*;

import java.time.Instant;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        Gson gson =
                new GsonBuilder()
                        .registerTypeAdapter( Instant.class , new Gson_InstantTypeAdapter() )
                        .create();

        // Write to JSON.
        Person person = new Person( "John Doe" , Instant.now() ); //For example: 2022-02-02T11:11:510Z
        String personAsJson = gson.toJson( person );

        System.out.println( "personAsJson = " + personAsJson );

        // Parse JSON.
        Person p = gson.fromJson( personAsJson , Person.class );

        System.out.println( "p.toString() = " + p );
    }
}
```

Comment: I am so sorry, the "//For example: 2022-02-02T11:11:510Z" comment I was using to illustrate the data that was not empty in LocalDateTime type. I was misused between LocalDateTime and Instant. So now, I am updated my question again. (Thank you for pointing out this mistake). I'll try with Instant and update to you. Just FYI, beside I also want to understand why Gson cannot serialize LocalDateTime type in android (You can see that the data was not empty, but the logs thrown out said that it cannot be parsed because it was null). Thank you so much for time helping me out.

Comment: Hi Basil, I tried with the Instant and it worked. However, I would love to know more about why I cannot serialize java.time.LocalDateTime with Gson. I searched the documents and they did not seem to fit my curiosity. I believe it relates to the Android Java APIs compatibility as well as Android SDK configuration... It would be great if you can give me some more clues like keywords, and terms.. so that I could research more about it. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @TrânVõBảo What happened when you tried writing a type adapter class for `LocalDateTime` in a fashion similar to what I showed you in a type adapter for `Instant`?